# LTSpice: How to start the step of a voltage source at a different time in the transient simulation than t=0s?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

If I have a complex circuit where things occur at different times instead of starting as soon as the simulation starts (t=0s), how do I setup those things to occur at different times in the simulation.

For example if I have a voltage source that should start it's step at t=1s, what can I do in LTSpice to ensure it's simulated this way?

Comment: Use a piecewise linear source that is 0 at 0, 0 at T-delta, and the desired voltage at T.  Delta is the simulation time step.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/425471/95619)?

Comment: Sorry, I felt I didn't explain my question well enough there and this was a better question.

Comment: Did you see the update to my answer? It specifically addresses your comment there.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the voltage source and select advanced, then use pulse or PWL options to set your desired parameters.

It’s better to explicitly set your desired rise time rather than selecting 0 and getting a default value.